# Unable to create a backup of the database

Tags: sql-server

Recently I requested access to database running on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Now I'm dbo owner and can 'insert', 'update', 'delete' and etc.

Currently I have to create a backup of the database but got this error:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_get_tape_devices', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

What should I do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably ask on [dba.se]

Comment: You don't have permission to run a backup, talk to your DBA

Comment: Have you tried backing up to disk?  (Instead of to tape.)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have sufficient permissions with db_owner.  You need to be added to the db_backupoperator role.  Note that this will give the ability to backup the database, but you may also need permissions for the file system or location you are writing the backup file.

Comment: Thanks, I will request that from DBA